# how to determine the encryption that was used to encrypt string?

Tags: encryption, aes

i have two strings

```
9d14be68d71e15449d7ace056905429e28e319949eace8521c6114da6223208b37b32e50c045da86eccae39e2034ec14

3081d302010104205f20ff52fe5b542b2901408a1cbd4fb19b33b105a6f7e9e2bb36c64bae1e3fcaa08185308182020101302c06072a8648ce3d0101022100fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f300604010004010704210279be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798022100fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141020101a12403220002000be91168a24103962a0a5e899a1ee557c52105770607b4b746e9f5da45427d
```

The first one is encrypted version of the second and the password is:

```
this sucks
```

So i want to find out the type of encryption that was used and how.
I will then use python to decrypt it as to experience cryptography on my own.
The above encryption was done by Bitcoin core app.
Some research say that the app uses AES CBC to encrypt the wallet data so extracted the data before and after encryption for this experiment.

How was the string encrypted?

Please bear with me i am still learning encryption.

Comment: Usually, this **should** not be determinable in an easy way. Such a string could be generated by a lot of encryption algorithms

Comment: @NicoHaase perhaps counting the length of an encrypted string is a good start but i do not know any output SHA or AES because i am still researching

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of knowing. Maybe take a look at [ciphertext indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability).

Your best chance is to brute force the cypher with your python script. Keep in mind that there are a lot of well-known encryption algorithms (AES, 3DES, ...), key lengths, encryption modes (CBC, CFB, ...) and padding options so this might not be even possible due to high number of combinations.

Also, there is another problem. You password ***this sucks*** is shorter than the key size encryption algorithms use. For example, AES requires keys to be either 128, 192 or 256 bits of length so you need to make your password of that length. There is no way of knowing what key stretching technique (PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, ...) or what hashing algorithm (SHA256, SHA512, ...) was used to achieve adequate key size.

This task is not impossible but highly improbable.

Comment: Oh i found something [link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_encryption)